# Error al generar un mapa

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, android-fragment, google-api

Estoy programando en android estudio un google maps para que aparezca mi ubicacion en tiempo real pero me salta un error que es este:
[image: El error se genera en esta parte del codigo: private void initMap() { if(isPermissionGranted){ if(isGPSenable()) { SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment); supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this); } } }]

El código seria

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    boolean isPermissionGranted;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mLocationClient;
    private int GPS_REQUEST_CODE = 9001;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        checkMyPermission();

        initMap();

        mLocationClient = new FusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view){ getCurrLoc();}
        });
    }

    private void initMap() {
        if(isPermissionGranted){
            if(isGPSenable()) {
                SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
                supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isGPSenable(){
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        boolean providerEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if(providerEnable){
            return true;
        }else{
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("GPS Permission")
                    .setMessage("El GPS es necesario para el uso de esta app")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", ((dialogInterface,i )-> {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, GPS_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }))
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .show();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

La linea con error seria esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el fragment:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutarse la app se cierra sin más y al usar debug lo que me muestra al compilar es ese error.
Lo que debería hacer es mostrar una pantalla típica de google maps y el botón para centrar la pantalla en mi ubicación actual.
¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Por favor recuerda que es preferible siempre agregar código en lugar de imágenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al obtener la referencia del Fragment con id `fragment` , esta no existe y por esa razón marca error al llamar el método `getMapAsync()` :

```
 SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
 supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

debes asegurar que este `Fragment` se encuentre definido en el archivo que se carga mediante `setContentView()` que es `activity_main.xml`

Comment: Pero ya esta declarada en setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  en el metodo onCreate al principio. Aun así sigue saliendo el error.

Comment: Esta declarado si, pero debes revisar que dentro de activity_main.xml se encuentre el Fragment que intentas cargar.